# SELECT DISTINCT still showing duplicate result

Tags: php

I have a HTML **select** form filled by SQL Query using SELECT DISTINCT...
The idea is to not show duplicate values from database, and it's almost working, but in some case it's giving a problem. To fill the SQL columns I'm using a PHP reading a TXT file with delimiters and explode function. If I have in the TXT file 10 duplicate columns, on my HTML  it shows 2, instead of only 1... And I note that 1 is with 9 of the entries from database, and the other one have 1 entry that is always the last line from TXT file.
Resuming: the last line of TXT file always duplicate on the HTML select form.
Checking the database, everything looks ok, I really don't know why it's duplicating always in the last one.
I told about the PHP that make the SQL entry because i'm not sure if the problem is in the PHP that contains the HTML select or in the PHP that fill the database... I believe that the problem is in the PHP with HTML select since I'm looking in the database and everything is ok. The SQL query in this php is like this:

```
<td class="formstyle"><select name="basenamelst" class="formstyle" id="basenamelst">
<option value="Any">Any</option>
<?
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT basename FROM dumpsbase where sold=0");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
    if($row['basename'] == "")
     {
    echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['basename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'">unknOwn</option>'; 
     }
    else
     {
       echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['basename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['basename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</option>'; 
     }
   }
?>
</select>
```

Remember: if I upload to database 10 duplicate columns, it shows 2 on select. One with 9 entries, and another with 1 entry (always the last line of my TXT file)...
Okay, many people told me to trim() the columns and it still showing duplicate... So I came to the conclusion that I have some issue while loading the TXT for database. Here is the code where I get the values to put on database:

```
$file = fopen($targetpath, "r") or exit("Unable to open uploaded file!");

while(!feof($file))
 {
   $line = fgets($file);
   $details = explode(" | ", $line);

   foreach($details as &$value) // clean each field
    {
      $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
      if($value == "")
     {
       $value = "NONE";
     }
     }
   unset($value);
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO dumpsbase VALUES('NULL', '$details[0]', '$details[1]', '$details[2]', '$details[3]', '$details[4]', '0', '$price', 'NONE', now(), 'NONE', 'NONE')") or die ("Uploading Error!");
```

Comment: I didn't really read all of that really long sentence but if you're getting what you think are duplicates with that SQL I would bet a dollar that you have one entry with trailing spaces/newlines. Do trim() on the entries before inserting them.

Comment: Two nitpicks with your code: 1) PHP short open tags (`<?`) are deprecated; use long tags (`<?php`) instead. 2) `$row['basename']` is being used in the `if` branch where we already know it's the empty string.

Comment: Show the results of running "SELECT DISTINCT basename FROM dumpsbase where sold=0" directly against the database engine.  Need to establish if it's a problem with the webpage display, the query, or the insertion of data.  That means looking at the data during each step.

Comment: When I execute the query directly in the database, it shows the duplicate results... I'll try to trim() it...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the error is when you are populating the table from the file, and that one of the values is ending up subtly different to the others.

The fact that it's the last line that differs makes me wonder if there are newline characters being included in each value (except that last line).

If this is the case, you should be able to correct it by running `trim()` or similar in your DB.

[Edit] Ideally, you want to do this as early as possible, i.e. correct the data rather than remembering it's wrong when you access it. If you can't find why the initial import is messing it up, you could correct the data immediately afterwards with `UPDATE dumpsbase SET basename = TRIM(basename)`

Comment: I did: UPDATE dumpsbase SET basename = TRIM(basename)
but it still showing duplicate results...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query to the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(basename) FROM dumpsbase WHERE sold=0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can help indeed, but the best solution would be to normalize data @ the database and correct the load data issue

Comment: I totally agree @TiagoCésarOliveira.

Comment: Yes I tried it but still showing duplicate results...
EDIT: in fact, it shows unknown on my html form, it shows duplicate when I execute the query directly from phpMyAdmin..

Comment: Yes I think too. It's the last group of characters in the TXT that is giving this error. The line is something like: **457896 | Binary | USA | 483724958498495=190 | 01**
The '|' is delimiter, and the value that get duplicate in html select is the last 01. I'm tryin to figure out how to solve.

Comment: I added the code where I put data from txt to sql database... look in the main post.